# Program of consumer Producer

Tags: java

I need to make a consumer producer problem for homework. I am stuck repeating the the thread. Only 1 object is produced and only 1 object is consumed. If object is present in array then producer does not produce and wait till consumer consumes it.

```
class PC extends Thread{
static int i=1;
static int storage[]=new int[1];
String info;

PC(String _info)
{
    this.info=_info;
}

public synchronized void consume()
{
    if(storage[0]==-1) 
    {   
        try { 
            System.out.println("C: 0" ); 
        wait(); 
        } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught"); 
        } 
    }

    else
        {
        System.out.println("C: " + storage[0]); 
        storage[0]=-1;
        i++;

        notify(); 
        }       
}

public synchronized void prod()
{
    if(storage[0]!=-1) 
    {   
        try { 
            System.out.println("P: 0" );
        wait(); 

        } catch(InterruptedException e) { 
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught"); 
        } 
    }
    else
        {
        storage[0]=i;

        System.out.println("P: " + storage[0]); 

        notify(); 
        }   
}

public void run()
{
    if(info=="producer"){

        prod();
    }
    else
        consume();
}


public static void main(String args[])
{

    storage[0]=-1;


    PC consumer =new PC("consumer");
    PC producer =new PC("producer");

    consumer.start();
    producer.start();



}
```

}

Comment: Comparing Strings with `==` is very suspicious. Use `"producer".equals(info)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BlockingQueue` which will be shared by `producer` and `consumer` threads. If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: NO i have to keep it simple. 
Thanks though

Comment: I cannot use blocking queue

Comment: @KaranShah once you know this, it will be in-fact very simple.

Comment: This problem is for homework. And i cannot use anything that my professor has not taught. So i cant use blocking queue

Comment: All i can use is sleep,join,wait,notify,notify all, sync

Comment: got it. I synced the array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a loop in your `run()` method. Either a `while-loop`, or if you want to produce/consume a certain amount of items, you can use a `for-loop`.

Pay attention to the String comparison too.

Comment: public void run()
 {
  while(true)
  {
  if("producer".equals(info)){
  
   prod();
  }
  else
   consume();
  }
 }

Comment: got it. I synced the array.

Answer (score 0):

> Only 1 object is produced and only 1 object is consumed.

Well, yeah:

> ```
> public void run()
> {
>     if(info=="producer"){
>
>         prod();
>     }
>     else
>         consume();
> }
> ```

(You also synchronize on different objects, so the threads will not share a monitor. This means that the class variable 'storage' is not protected either.)